Unable to use custom controller method as route for API Platform in Laravel
I'm starting to play around with Laravel's implementation of API Platform.
What I need to do is to have an create a custom route that points to a specific controller's method. So far the documentation does not show any example on this use case.
I tried soemthing like this :
#[ApiResource]
#[GetCollection]
#[Get(
    uriTemplate: '/jobs/test',
    controller: JobController::class . '::test'
)]
class Job extends Model
{ ... }

// JobController.php
public function test()
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'This is my test',
    ]);
}

But all i get is the first result of my jobs in the database. but not the response inside test().
Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

The solution I was looking for is to use api platform state provider instead of a controller.

I don't know about api-platform.com, but the way you would specify a controller + method for Laravel route is: [JobController::class, 'test']

Well unfortunately that does not work for api-platform, controller takes a value of ?string, but well tried !
